# Connection refused in kubernetes while calling Jasperreports service

Tags: kubernetes, jasperserver

I have deployed Jasperreports Server in K8s.

Configuration file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jasperreports
  labels:
    app: jasperreports
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jasperreports
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jasperreports
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jasperreports
        image: k3d-report-center-registry.localhost:12345/jasperserver
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8082
        env:
        - name: JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: mariadb-database
              name: some-configmap
        - name: JASPERREPORTS_DATABASE_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: some-secret
              key: mariadb-username
        - name: MARIADB_HOST
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: mariadb_host
              name: some-configmap
        - name: MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: mariadb_port
              name: some-configmap
        - name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "yes"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jasperreports
spec:
  selector:
    app: jasperreports
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8082
      targetPort: 8082
```

There is another REST service (Service-A) which needs to communicate with the Jasperreports Server instance to call a REST endpoint, this service expects an environment variable (JASPERSERVER_ADDR) whose value is defined in a ConfigMap like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: some-configmap
data:
  jasperserver_addr: "http://jasperreports:8082/"
```

However I am getting the following Connection refused exception

```
2021-12-17 17:14:45,238 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.exe.MainClientExec] (executor-thread-1) Opening connection {}->http://jasperreports:8082
2021-12-17 17:14:45,240 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] (executor-thread-1) Connecting to jasperreports/10.43.60.80:8082
2021-12-17 17:14:45,240 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] (executor-thread-1) http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
2021-12-17 17:14:45,240 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.exe.MainClientExec] (executor-thread-1) Connection discarded
2021-12-17 17:14:45,240 DEBUG [org.apa.htt.imp.con.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] (executor-thread-1) Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://jasperreports:8082][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 50; total allocated: 0 of 50]
2021-12-17 17:14:45,240 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.cli.jax.i18n] (executor-thread-1) RESTEASY004672: Client send processing failure.: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to jasperreports:8082 [jasperreports/10.43.60.80] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
```

Service-A has the following entry in the application.poperties file:

```
jasperserver/mp-rest/url=${JASPERSERVER_ADDR:http://localhost:8549/}jasperserver/rest_v2/
```

Any idea why?

Comment: The two Pods are in the same namespace, right?

Comment: yes they are in the same ns

Comment: Could you add the manifest of Service-A to your question?